# Oracle SQL index rows based on group by/ parent row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 1 table, which refers by value to rows in the same table

Example table:

```
ID  PARENT_ID   NAME
1   0           john
2   1           jane
3   2           smigy
4   2           gujo
5   1           duby
6   1           ruby
7   5           foo
8   2           bar
9   3           baz
10  3           qux
```

The root-parent has parent 0 (just so it wouldn't be null), in this case there's

- 1 root-parent - parent(0)=1.
- root-parent has 1lvl children - parent(1)=2;5;6.
- 1lvl children has 2lvl children - parent(2)=3;4;8. parent(5)=7. parent(6) has nothing.
- 2lvl children has 3lvl children - parent(3)=9;10. parent(4) has nothing. parent(8) has nothing.
- There is no lvl4 children or anything with depth beyond 4.

And I need to create a script (presumably SQL query - need to avoid function/procedure/etc.) that would index rows based on their position under their parent.
Just like if I'd select all root-parent's and get (rownum-1)

The goal table should look like this:

```
ID  PARENT_ID   NAME    ROW_INDEX
1   0           john    0
2   1           jane    0
3   2           smigy   0
4   2           gujo    1
5   1           duby    1
6   1           ruby    2
7   5           foo     0
8   2           bar     2
9   3           baz     0
10  3           qux     1
```

I'm planing to add this column and thus the query will be executed only once. I've played by selecting seperate depth rows, but then I don't really know how to count inside/between group by (even if that is possible).

P.S. A better/good column name suggestion would also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User row_number()

```
select mt.*, row_number() over(partition by parent_id order by id) - 1 as rn
from MyTable mt
```